# woocommerce_order_status_completed action hook not working

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am developing woocommerce extension wher i need to perform some task after order is successfully completed. For that I started coding.
I used following code in constructor of my class.

```
add_action(‘woocommerce_order_status_completed’,array(&$this,’insert_points’));
```

Then I defined function as follows:

```
public function insert_points($order_id)
{
   global $woocommerce, $table_prefix;
   $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
   var_dump($order);
}
```

But it is not working.
Can anybody please help me using code sample.

Comment: Use simple quotes `'`, not curly quotes.

Comment: I would say that this question is not off-topic, is specific to WordPress, is not generic, and WooCommerce is not a third party plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be try this

```
add_action(‘woocommerce_order_status_completed’,array(&$this,’insert_points’),10,1);
```

add_action hooks has last argument which specifies how many arguments to pass to function in hook.

Comment: No it is not working. :( Is there any other solution??

Comment: @JaykumarPatil "woocommerce_payment_complete" is also relavant hook.

Comment: Still it is not working and I want to run the code only after status is changed.

Comment: Thanks for your support actually instead of echoing the data I inserted some value in database and it worked. Thank for your support

Comment: i use this for card payments `woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_completed`